# plist segment control save issue

Tags: iphone, ios4, nsmutablearray

I have a issue with this peice of code, I am trying to save some data to a plist for later use, and if the user reopens the view, it should have the current segment selected for each segment control on my view.

however when I try and save the information, it crashes on the line

```
[array addObject:gender];
```

please help :) it gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS

```
-(IBAction)genderSelection:(id)sender
{
    if([sender selectedSegmentIndex] == kSwitchesSegmentIndex)
    {
        gender = @"Male";
        //NSLog(gender);
    }
    else {
        gender = @"Female";
        //NSLog(gender);
    }

}

-(IBAction)contactTypeSelection:(id)sender
{
    if([sender selectedSegmentIndex] == kSwitchesSegmentIndex)
    {
        contactType = @"a";
        //NSLog(gender);
    }
    else {
        contactType = @"b";
        //NSLog(gender);
    }

}

-(IBAction)saveData:(id)sender
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [array removeAllObjects];

    [array addObject:field1.text];
    [array addObject:field2.text];
    [array addObject:gender];
    [array addObject:contactType];

    [array writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];
    [array release];
}

-(NSString *)dataFilePath
{
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];

    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:kFilename];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath];

    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
    {
        NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

        field1.text = [array objectAtIndex:0];
        field2.text = [array objectAtIndex:1];

        gender = [array objectAtIndex:2];
        contactType = [array objectAtIndex:3];

        if([gender isEqualToString:@"Male"])
        {
            genderSegment.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            genderSegment.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
        }

        if([contactType isEqualToString:@"a"])
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }


        [array release];
    }
}

-(IBAction)textDone:(id)sender
{
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}



- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [gender release]; //need to release
    [contactType release]; //need to release
    [field1 release]; //need to release
    [field2 release]; //need to release
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    gender = @"Male";
    contactType = @"a";
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    gender = nil; //need to release
    contactType = nil; //need to release
    field1 = nil ; //need to release
    field2 = nil; //need to release
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't didn't initialize your `gender` property. You need:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.gender=[[NSString alloc]init];

    self.gender = @"Male";

//so something here

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

}
```

**NOTE:** If you use the `@synthesize` compiler directive then you need to the self-dot notation everywhere to refer to the property e.g. `self.gender`.

Comment: i declared it in the .h using the @property and synthesizing it.

Comment: s u r right.but u have instantiate if u want to store something and live on that .so use alloc and init then store.now u can rent that memory until u release it

Comment: it now crashes on the viewcontroller before it ( the controller posted is pushed onto the navigation controller. it crashes with the same message but on a line with [self.navigationController pushViewController:userController animated:YES];

Comment: change everywhere what i said

Comment: ok it looks like its not crashing, but my segment isnt being selected to the one that has been selected. For example, segment index 1 isnt the one highlighted.

Comment: if u synthesized the  genderSegment also then u have to use same like with self.genderSegment

Comment: if(self.gender == @"Male") try this also and nslog them before this

Comment: your gunna hate me but i forgot to set the IBOutlets hence why they werent being selected. thankyou for your help sorting out the crashes tho :D

Comment: @madhu You are leaking memory in `self.gender=[[NSString alloc]init];`  and since you are reassigning immediately, you should remove that line.

Comment: he will use dealloc fun with [self.gender release];